# how to set up a captive portal to access localhost website

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, wifi, captivenetwork

So I have an ubuntu-12.04 linux box with a webserver on it, and it acts as an access point(hostpad) with dhcp.  I want to set up a simple captive portal to force who ever connects to my access point to go to my webserver when they open a browser.

Chillispot/coovachilli seemed overly complicated and heavy weight.  Any suggestions on another approach or maybe a simple node.js program to do the same.

I don not need access to the outsite internet or security/login accounts.

Comment: Chillispot is really easy to use for what you need. Try a good tutorial and you will see that.